# Flowable task vs Http Task

Tags: flowable

I want to understand the main difference between a flowable task and http task. Why should we prefer one over the other and when is it better to use flowable task or http task?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by Flowable Task? In case you mean the Service Task then the Http Task is just an extension of the Service task that has specific functionality provided out of the box to easily send HTTP requests. You can also achieve this by implementing some logic to a Service Task. The only difference is that the Http Task is specified for sending Http requests and you can simply use it and provide the endpoint you want to call.